# AngularJS Test that a promise has been called inside a promise

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, karma-runner

I have this method in a service:

```
this.getCoords = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  geolocation.getLocation().then(function(data) { // line 29 in Karma output
    var coords = _.pick(data.coords, 'latitude', 'longitude');
    return deferred.resolve(coords);
  }, function(reason) {
    return deferred.reject(reason);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

As `geolocation` is a module by itself, I just want to test that `geolocation.getLocation()` promise has indeed been called.

What I've done so far:

```
 ...

 geolocationGetLocationSpy = spyOn(geolocation, 'getLocation');

 ...

 describe('getCoords()', function() {

   it('should call geolocation.getLocation()', function() {
     Googlemaps.getCoords(); // line 64 in Karma output

     // promise won't get resolved until a digest
     $rootScope.$apply();

     expect(geolocationGetLocationSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });

 });
```

However I get:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Mac OS X) Service: Googlemaps getCoords() should call geolocation.getLocation() FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'geolocation.getLocation().then')
        at /Users/jviotti/Projects/Temporal/angular/angular-geolocation/app/scripts/services/googleMaps.js:29
        at /Users/jviotti/Projects/Temporal/angular/angular-geolocation/test/spec/services/googleMaps.js:64
```

What else should I do?

Comment: What is `geolocationGetLocationSpy`? If I wanted to spy on the `getLocation()` method, I would do:  `spyOn(goelocation, 'getLocation');` at the beginning of the test. Then at the end you can expect that it was called: `expect(geoLocation.getLocation).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Comment: `geolocationGetLocationSpy = spyOn(geolocation, 'getLocation');`. Assigning the spy to a variable has the same results. Have this pattern in almost all my tests. It should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern you used seems fine. Try doing this:

```
geolocationGetLocationSpy = spyOn(geolocation, 'getLocation').andCallThrough();

// or the Jasmine 2.0 syntax
geolocationGetLocationSpy = spyOn(geolocation, 'getLocation').and.callThrough();
```

When you spy on a method, the original method is overwritten with a method that makes all the "spy on" functionality work. That phony version of `getLocation()` isn't returning the same value as the original method (the original method appears to return a `promise`).

To do that, you can add the `andCallThrough()`, now the phony version of `getLocation()` will invoke the original method as well as carrying out the "spy on" functionality.

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks, though you wrote `addCallThrough()` instead of `andCallThrough()` the second time :)

Comment: in the latest version, this is now `spyOn().and.callThrough()`